# Hide Previous Div if Height = 0

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do something that seems so simple. I have a DIV that is a heading and a sibling DIV that has content. If the content DIV's height is equal to 0, I want to hide the heading DIV which is it's previous sibling. Below is my script and fiddle

```
$(function() {  
    if ( $('div.grid').height() < 1 ) {
        $(this).prev('.titletohide').css('display', 'none');            
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mj5t4x9g/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. The first is that `$('div.grid')` matches more than one element. And `$(this)` does not refer to what you think it does. Try this:

```js
$('div.grid').each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() < 1) {
    $(this).prev('.titletohide').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titletohide">
  Heading 1
</div>
<div class="grid" style="height:0px;"><span style="display:none">text text</span></div>

<div class="titletohide">
  Heading 2
</div>
<div class="grid">
  more more
</div>
```